# Need to sort a field with numeric and alpha numeric values in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create mapping for a field which will need to be used only for exact matches and sorting. I don't want to set primary data type as text as I need to do only exact match.

```
{
  "index_patterns": "*",
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "my_field": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": true,
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Mapping definition for [my_field] has unsupported parameters:  [fielddata : true]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [doc]: Mapping definition for [my_field] has unsupported parameters:  [fielddata : true]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Mapping definition for [my_field] has unsupported parameters:  [fielddata : true]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

The problem is that without `fielddata` sorting is no happening properly. For example following is the sample `asc` sort output:

`"90000001"
"90000001"
""
""
""
"90000008"
"9100000"`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `fielddata: true` for `keyword` fields. You can also remove `index: true` as it is the default setting for `keyword` fields:

Simply like this:

```
{
  "index_patterns": "*",
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "my_field": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Then you need to explain in a bit more details what you have tried and what doesn't work. Showing an example is always what works best !

Comment: Added in question

Comment: The problem is that the values can be "alphanumeric" and there's no way to properly sort mixed numeric and alphanumeric values...